# Sprite movement basically right but

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, flashdevelop, double-click

This is basically just drag and double click to set (so drag is temporarily disabled) but the sprite doesn't keep with the mouse- can someone point me to better code- otherwise I'll with go with this- so much more to do.

```
//The initial event performed when the button is first clicked;
internal var m_nDoubleClickSpeed:Number = 300;
internal var m_toMouse:Number;
internal var moveready:Boolean = false;
internal var initalx:uint;
internal var initialy:uint;
internal var move:Boolean;

internal function clickDoubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (isSet == false) {
        this.startDrag();
    }

    if (isNaN(m_toMouse)==false) {
        clearTimeout(m_toMouse);
        HandleDoubleClick();
    } else {
        m_toMouse = setTimeout(HandleSingleClick, m_nDoubleClickSpeed);
    }
}

internal function HandleSingleClick():void {
    trace("HandleSingleClick");
    trace("isSet");
    trace(isSet);
    this.stopDrag();

     m_toMouse = NaN;
}

internal function HandleDoubleClick():void {
    if (isSet == false) {
        isSet = true;
        this.stopDrag()
    } else {
        isSet = false; 
    }

    trace("HandleDoubleClick");
    m_toMouse = NaN;  
}

internal function goodX(inX:Number):Number {
    if (inX < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (inX > (stage.stageWidth) ) {       
        return (stage.stageWidth);
    }

    return inX;
}

internal function goodY(inY:Number):Number {
    if (inY < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (inY > stage.stageHeight) {
        return stage.stageHeight;
    }
    return inY;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. What happens when `startDrag()` is actually called? Native dragging should position the sprite so its anchor point should be at mouse position. Perhaps your sprites are not aligned with their (0,0) local point to be within the sprite's contents? The code seems to be correct in dragging part.

Comment: Is it a function of running through

Comment: debugger Flash Player.

Comment: No, it's a native dragging mechanism of Flash, `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` work in any version of FP (9.0 and above, at the very least, maybe lower). Read [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) for details.

Comment: I mean Flash Debugger adds a processing overhead (log creating) so the mouse could move out of the area of sprite and trigger an effect mouse up event. How do I interrogate (flash develop) or flash player to see what its doing?

Comment: At least add mouse down and mouse up listeners to that sprite, also listen for `ROLL_OUT` event that occurs when you first mouse down on sprite then move mouse away from sprite. And I don't think that extra overhead causes anything bad with debugger FP versus release FP.

Comment: Going with this internal function draglocation(e:Event):void
   {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draglocation);
    initialx = this.x;
    initialy = this.y;
    if (isSet == false)
    {
    stage.addChild(this) 
    this.startDrag();
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clickcheck);}
   }
   internal function clickcheck(e:Event):void
   {
    if (isSet == false)
    { this.stopDrag(); }
    finalx = this.x;
    finaly = this.y;
    if ((sqrt((finaly - initialy) ^ 2 + (finalx - initialx) ^ 2)) < 5)
    {HandleDoubleClick();
    
    
    
    
   }

Comment: "trainingtutorials101.com/2011/02/as3-dragging-and-dropping-tutorial-as3.html"- this says that the Sprite or Movie Clip can get left behind by the mouse pointer so my experience was nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. So you want to start drag on single click and drag until doubleclicked right? If so you can try something like that:

```
public class ClickAndDrag extends Sprite
{
    private var clickTimeout:uint;
    private var doubleClickSpeed:int = 500;
    private var clickedOnce:Boolean;
    private var mouseOnClick:Point;
    private var isDragging:Boolean;

    public function ClickAndDrag() 
    {
        graphics.beginFill(Math.random()*0xffffff, 1);
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
        graphics.endFill();

        this.buttonMode = true;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseDown);
    }

    private function handleMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            if (clickedOnce)
                handleDoubleClicked();
            else
            {
                //if it's not clicket within next doubleClickSpeed ms then doubleClickSpeed will be set to false;
                clickedOnce = true;
                clickTimeout = setTimeout( handleClickTimeout, doubleClickSpeed );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            handleClickAndDrag();
        }
    }

    //clicked once when dragging
    private function handleClickOnce():void 
    {
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginFill(Math.random()*0xffffff, 1);
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
        graphics.endFill();
    }

    //clicked once when not dragging
    private function handleClickAndDrag():void 
    {
        isDragging = true;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleFrame);
        mouseOnClick = new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);
    }

    //doubleclicked when dragging
    private function handleDoubleClicked():void 
    {
        clearTimeout(clickTimeout);
        clickedOnce = false;            
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleFrame);
        isDragging = false;
    }

    private function handleClickTimeout():void 
    {
        clickedOnce = false;
        handleClickOnce();
    }

    private function handleFrame(e:Event):void 
    {
        this.x = stage.mouseX - mouseOnClick.x;
        this.y = stage.mouseY - mouseOnClick.y;
    }


}
```

It basically waits for mousedown and if it's already dragging it checks if you clicked once (changes color) ot twice (stops dragging). Or if it's not dragging yet then it starts dragging. You may also want to handle leaving the stage (Event.MOUSE_LEAVE).

Comment: No I need to set the tile in place at its current position so that it can't be moved using either double click or single click and drag the tile using a normal mouse drag mechanic. There are limited number of spots on screen where the tile can be placed so as to be unable to move at its current position but I just limiting it two rectangular areas on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Misiek- I will study it for anything relevant but it was to the wrong question- two separate action- drag preferably simply drag by mouse down and mouse up to complete and either click or double click with tile not moved which either disables or enables the tile to be dragged- all tiles to be used are initially enabled.